# How to Not Remember Credentials by Default in Wireless Profile - Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Is there a GPO or policy that prevents windows from remembering the credentials of the wireless profiles to which it connects?

By default, when connecting to any Wi-Fi network, Windows activates this checkbox by default in its Wireless Profile:
"Remember my credentials for this connection each time i'm logged on"
[image: Wireless Profile]

I need to have that box unchecked by default, so the user must always enter the wifi access credentials every time they log in.

I know it can be done using the netsh command in a script that runs on every logout, but I need to do it using some GPO or registry key.

Is there anything to try and avoid using a script?

Comment: Sorry, yes im in AD environment, im searched through the options i have in gpedit but no luck